# datatables individual column searching functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using datatables in my application and it works well, however I would like to implement the ability to search individual columns of the table.  I found [this page](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) and can get it to work with the hard coded data example, however I am having trouble applying it to my particular code (I am using an api to populate the table).  My current code that works without individual column searching is below, thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $("#notifications").DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: "/api/notification",
      dataSrc: ""
    },
    columns: [{
        data: "id",
        render: function(data, type, notification) {
          return "<a href='/notifications/NewSubmission/" + notification.id + "'>" + notification.id + "</a>";
        }

      },

      {
        data: "address1",

      },
      {
        data: "address2",

      },
      {
        data: "address3",

      },

      {
        data: "town",

      },
      {
        data: "county",

      },
      {
        data: "postCode",

      },
      {
        data: "local.name",

      },

      {
        data: "id",
        render: function(data) {
          return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-notification-id=" + data + ">Delete</button>";
        }

      }

    ]

  });

  $("#notifications").on("click", ".js-delete", function() {
    var button = $(this);

    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this notification?", function(result) {
      if (result) {

        $.ajax({
          url: "/api/notification/" + button.attr("data-notification-id"),
          method: "DELETE",
          success: function() {
            table.row(button.parents("tr")).remove().draw();

          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<h2>Index</h2>

<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>DataTables example - Individual column searching (text inputs)</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/media/images/favicon.png">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://www.datatables.net/rss.xml">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/site-examples.css?_=170d96f69db52446b9aa21d2653da1f4">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<style type="text/css" class="init">
  tfoot input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/site.js?_=2ec2144600499da11df5c1cee6ac09df">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/dynamic.php?comments-page=examples%2Fapi%2Fmulti_filter.html" async>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/demo.js">
</script>


<table id="notifications" class="table table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>

    <tr>

      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Address Line 1</th>
      <th>Address Line 2</th>
      <th>Address Line 3</th>
      <th>Town</th>
      <th>County</th>
      <th>Post Code</th>
      <th>Local Authority</th>
      <th>Delete</th>

    </tr>

  </thead>

</table>
```

Comment: What's problem? The example in linked shared by you include search on all columns. Thats what you are looking for. please specify.

Comment: Yes I know, but when I am trying to apply the javascript in the linked example to my code, I can't get it to work.

Comment: Could you include the JavaScript you're trying to apply that doesn't work in your question?

Comment: I realized that I'd made a daft mistake & missed the table footer from my HTML and that was the problem.  I'll add the now working code in case anyone finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Working version

```
<h2>Index</h2>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>DataTables example - Individual column searching (text inputs)</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/media/images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://www.datatables.net/rss.xml">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/site-examples.css?_=170d96f69db52446b9aa21d2653da1f4">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <style type="text/css" class="init">
        tfoot input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 3px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/site.js?_=2ec2144600499da11df5c1cee6ac09df">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/dynamic.php?comments-page=examples%2Fapi%2Fmulti_filter.html" async>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/demo.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" class="init">


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#notifications tfoot th').each(function () {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
            });

            var table = $("#notifications").DataTable({        

                    ajax: {
                        url: "/api/notification",
                        dataSrc: ""
                    },

                    columns: [
                        {
                            data: "id",
                            render: function (data, type, notification) {
                                return "<a href='/notifications/NewSubmission/" + notification.id + "'>" + notification.id + "</a>";
                            }

                        },

                        {
                            data: "address1",

                        },
                        {
                            data: "address2",

                        },
                        {
                            data: "address3",

                        },

                        {
                            data: "town",

                        },
                         {
                             data: "county",

                         },
                          {
                              data: "postCode",

                          },
                        {
                            data: "local.name",

                        },

                    {
                        data: "id",
                        render: function (data) {
                            return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-notification-id=" + data + ">Delete</button>";
                        }

                    }

                    ]


            });
            table.columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;

                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
        } );

                            $("#notifications").on("click", ".js-delete", function () {
                                var button = $(this);

                                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this notification?", function (result) {
                                    if (result) {

                                        $.ajax({
                                            url: "/api/notification/" + button.attr("data-notification-id"),
                                            method: "DELETE",
                                            success: function () {
                                                table.row(button.parents("tr")).remove().draw();

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            });       

    </script>

    <table id="notifications" class="table table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>

            <tr>

                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Address Line 1</th>
                <th>Address Line 2</th>
                <th>Address Line 3</th>
                <th>Town</th>
                <th>County</th>
                <th>Post Code</th>
                <th>Local Authority</th>
                <th>Delete</th>

            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Address Line 1</th>
                <th>Address Line 2</th>
                <th>Address Line 3</th>
                <th>Town</th>
                <th>County</th>
                <th>Post Code</th>
                <th>Local Authority</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

    </table>
```